# When i exit to my application, shall threads which is created from ndk, die with app or i should kill those threads?

Tags: android, memory, android-ndk, pthreads

I developed an app in android with ndk and device's memory usage is increasing even the app closed. I think that because of threads that I created in ndk. I can't observe any memory leak with memory analyzer. What should I do?

When I exit to my application, shall threads which is created from ndk, die with app or I should kill those threads?

Answer (score 0):

Threads will automatically be killed when the parent activity, which created those threads, is killed.

Comment: Doesn't matter where you create the threads. Once an activity is killed, every resource with it also gets killed. Unless you choose to save them for the time when your app restarts.